# How to open two separate tabs in same google chrome window using webdriver and python?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, chrome, remote-webdriver

I need to test interacting with two tabs in Chrome. I've written a test in Python using Webdriver where I open Chrome with one tab.

I need to open a second tab (similarly to using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) so I can interact with both tabs. My plan is to copy text from Tab 1 and paste it into one of the fields on Tab 2, and vice versa.

**How do I use Python and WebDriver to open a new tab and switch between tabs?**

Comment: I've edited your question to make it more obvious what you're asking. You're welcome to revert my edit if you don't think I understood what you meant.

Comment: no it's okay thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Opening a New Tab

You do it the same way you would with a keyboard. `Control + t`, or `Command + t` if using a Mac.

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com")

page = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')

page.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't') 

#new tab is open
#navigate to second url

driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com/')
```

## Switching Tabs

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715942/how-do-i-switch-to-the-active-tab-in-selenium) is what you're looking for.

**1** - Switch between the tabs using the send_keys (CONTROL + TAB)

```
self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.TAB)
```

**2** - Switch between the tabs using the using ActionsChains (CONTROL+TAB)

```
actions = ActionChains(self.driver)      
actions.key_down(Keys.CONTROL).key_down(Keys.TAB).key_up(Keys.TAB).key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

**3** - Another approach could make usage of the Selenium methods to check current window and move to another one:

You can use

```
driver.window_handles
```

to find a list of window handles and after try to switch using following methods.

```
- driver.switch_to.active_element      
- driver.switch_to.default_content
- driver.switch_to.window
```

`driver.close()` will close the specific tab that the web driver is on.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the below code, windows[1] will switch to the newly opened tab and windows[0] will switch back to the original tab.

```
    windows = driver.window_handles
    driver.switch_to.window(windows[1])
    driver.switch_to.window(windows[0])
```